# Can you trilinear sample a non volume texture?

Tags: opengl, directx, graphics, graphics-programming

Let's say that i have a regular 2d texture (not a volume texture).  Is it possible to do trilinear texture sampling of that texture even though it isn't a volume texture in opengl or directx?

Specifically, if i had a 2x4 texture laid out like below where **A** through **H** are pixels:

**A B**
**C D**
**E F**
**G H**

What I'd like to get is a trilinear sample being the result of linearly interpolating the bilinear sampling of (**A**,**B**,**C**,**D**) and (**E**,**F**,**G**,**H**).

I know i could take two bilinear texture samples and lerp them to get what I want, but is there a hardware supported way to do this?

Comment: Can you offer a bit more context about why you want to blend two adjacent pixel quads like this? What formula determines the third interpolation factor?

Comment: Sure thanks for asking! It'll be interesting to hear if it makes a difference.  Basically, if it were a 2x2x2 volume texture, there would be a single value that was used as the interpolation for all three axes. Basically I'd be sampling along the diagonal only.

Comment: As for why, I'm trying to interpolate some data stored in textures (don't want to get into details). If I'm able to do this, I'll be able to store the data in a more efficient pattern and use smaller textures.

Comment: This is equivalent to a single lerp between A and the average of the whole 2x2x2 block (if t <= 0.5), or between the average and H (if t >= 0.5). So you could pre-process your texture into a single line of pixels and use a conventional sample. That would be about 2n pixels of storage instead of n^3.

Comment: I'll have to think about that a bit and see if it applies. No way you know of to do trilinear texture sampling on a 2d texture though? (Without using mimaps of course!)

Comment: Hey @DMGregory, I don't think what you said is right.  I made a quick little C++ program to verify and it looks like they are not the same.  It kind of makes sense too because trilinear interpolation is a cubic operation, so shouldn't be able to be smashed down to a lerp.    Check it out:
http://pastebin.com/4d0MJxd3

Comment: You're right, hasty late-night math on my part. Sorry about that.
The lerp formula is A + t(B + C + E - 3A) + t^2(3A + F + G - 2B - 2C - 2E) + t^3(B + C + E + H - A - D - F - G). I don't think there's anything in hardware that will apply this lerp formula to texture data that's being read as 2D.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24080/discussion-between-dmgregory-and-alan-wolfe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, unless you read the involved pixels into a pixel shader, and then do the interpolation in the shader program manually.